# htaccess redirect 301 from old domain to new domain + folder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I know this questions have been asked a million times but it's hard to fit them in every specific case. so i will try to explain my scenario

Google indexed my old domain urls with something like

```
www.oldDomain.com/city/newyork
```

and i want to redirect to

```
www.newDomain.com/newParameter/newyork
```

**NOTE**: both domains point to the same host, same folder.

what's the best way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your old host use this rule in site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?olddomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.newDomain.com/newParameter%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=302]
```

Comment: thanks, but I'm using the same host, basically same server just I want to redirect every old urls to the new one

Comment: Ok in that case try my updated rule in site root .htaccess